# How to get the IP range of a CIDR

Tags: go, ip, cidr

How can I get the start and end for v4 and v6 ip addresses of a CIDR? I don't care about addresses which are between.

I have checked the `net` library and parseCIDR does not return this information. Is there an idiomatic way to calculate the ip range of a CIDR which will work for v6 and v4 addresses alike?

For example, given the CIDR `2001:db8:a0b:12f0::1/32` I would expect
`2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000` and `2001:0db8:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff` returned as the start and end addresses respectively.

Comment: As you can see from [the `net` package documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net), this is not a built-in function, and requests for 3rd-party libraries are off-topic for SO.

Comment: @Adrian I edited the question to not mention third party libraries.

Comment: [net.IP is just a byte slice](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IP), making this is a fairly easy exercise in bit flipping. For a /32 net set the twelve trailing bytes all to 0x00 or 0xff, for instance.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/XEvv-_kStoL

Comment: @Peter That is working for me. Can you submit as an answer and add some info on how it works?

Comment: @Peter I did also find this solution https://gist.github.com/mzimmerman/78e19eeb2393f9d6ec2ab063d9338273 . I don't really know enough about go internals to know which is better (more efficient)

Comment: I'm on my phone and can't be bothered to write a proper answer. It's really just flipping the trailing bits either to all ones or to all zeroes. That gist seems very convoluted. It's silly to flip bits one at a time when you already have the address and mask in congruent byte slices. I can't imagine that being faster than going byte-wise.

Comment: @Peter Ok, well thanks for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192680/discussion-between-jack-tuck-and-peter).

Answer (score 0):

Using the [IPAddress Go library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/), this code will do it for either IPv4 or IPv6.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/seancfoley/ipaddress-go/ipaddr"
)

func main() {
    ipRange("2001:db8:a0b:12f0::1/32")
    ipRange("1.2.3.1/16")
}

func ipRange(cidr string) {
    block := ipaddr.NewIPAddressString(cidr).GetAddress().ToPrefixBlock()
    addr := block.WithoutPrefixLen()
    fmt.Printf("addr %s block %s lower %s upper %s\n", 
        cidr, block, addr.GetLower(), addr.GetUpper())
}
```

Output:

```
addr 2001:db8:a0b:12f0::1/32 block 2001:db8::/32 lower 2001:db8:: upper 2001:db8:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
addr 1.2.3.1/16 block 1.2.0.0/16 lower 1.2.0.0 upper 1.2.255.255
```